# Open specific filetypes in their own applications with the help of a WPF application

Tags: wpf

Situation of what I currently have:

- WPF Application
- files with the .ptb/.gpx/.gp4/.gp5 extensions.
- the applications to open these files are installed on my computer.

Now my question is, how would I let my WPF application open these files in the applications that these filetypes target? Example: .gpx files opening in 'Guitar Pro'?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will open your file with the program that is associated with the specific file type:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("yourfile.gpx")
```